# IndexError multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

I'm getting an IndexError using multiprocessing to process parts of a pandas DataFrame in parallel. `vacancies` is a pandas DataFrame containing several vacancies, of which one column is the raw text.

```
def addSkillRelevance(vacancies):
    skills = pickle.load(open("skills.pkl", "rb"))

    vacancies['skill'] = ''
    vacancies['skillcount'] = 0
    vacancies['all_skills_in_vacancy'] = ''
    new_vacancies = pd.DataFrame(columns=vacancies.columns)

    for vacancy_index, vacancy_row in vacancies.iterrows():

        #Create a df for which each row is a found skill (with the other attributes of the vacancy)
        per_vacancy_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=vacancies.columns)
        all_skills_in_vacancy = []
        skillcount = 0

        for skill_index, skill_row in skills.iterrows():

            #Making the search for the skill in the text body a bit smarter
            spaceafter = ' ' + skill_row['txn_skill_name'] + ' '
            newlineafter = ' ' + skill_row['txn_skill_name'] + '\n'
            tabafter = ' ' + skill_row['txn_skill_name'] + '\t'

            #Statement that returns true if we find a variation of the skill in the text body
            if((spaceafter in vacancies.at[vacancy_index,'body']) or (newlineafter in vacancies.at[vacancy_index,'body']) or (tabafter in vacancies.at[vacancy_index,'body'])):
                #Adding the skill to the list of skills found in the vacancy
                all_skills_in_vacancy.append(skill_row['txn_skill_name'])

                #Increasing the skillcount
                skillcount += 1

                #Adding the skill to the row
                vacancies.at[vacancy_index,'skill'] = skill_row['txn_skill_name']

                #Add a row to the vacancy df where 1 row, means 1 skill
                per_vacancy_df = per_vacancy_df.append(vacancies.iloc[vacancy_index])

        #Adding the list of all found skills in the vacancy to each (skill) row
        per_vacancy_df['all_skills_in_vacancy'] = str(all_skills_in_vacancy)
        per_vacancy_df['skillcount'] = skillcount

        #Adds the individual vacancy df to a new vacancy df
        new_vacancies = new_vacancies.append(per_vacancy_df)  
    return(new_vacancies)

def executeSkillScript(vacancies):
        from multiprocessing import Pool

        vacancies = vacancies.head(100298)

        num_workers = 47
        pool = Pool(num_workers)

        vacancy_splits = np.array_split(vacancies, num_workers)
        results_list = pool.map(addSkillRelevance,vacancy_splits)
        new_vacancies = pd.concat(results_list, axis=0)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

executeSkillScript(vacancies)
```

The function `addSkillRelevance()` takes in a pandas DataFrame and outputs a pandas DataFrame (with more columns). For some reason, after finishing all the multiprocessing, I get an IndexError on `results_list = pool.map(addSkillRelevance,vacancy_splits)`. I'm quite stuck as I don't know how to handle the error. Does anyone have tips as to why the IndexError is occurring?

The error:

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7cb04a51c051> in <module>()
----> 1 executeSkillScript(vacancies)

<ipython-input-9-5195d46f223f> in executeSkillScript(vacancies)
     14 
     15     vacancy_splits = np.array_split(vacancies, num_workers)
---> 16     results_list = pool.map(addSkillRelevance,vacancy_splits)
     17     new_vacancies = pd.concat(results_list, axis=0)
     18 

~/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    264         in a list that is returned.
    265         '''
--> 266         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    267 
    268     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

~/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    642             return self._value
    643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
    645 
    646     def _set(self, i, obj):

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

As per the suggestion

Comment: Could you include the code in `addSkillRelevance`? The error is likely coming from an operation you do on the `vacancies` dataframe.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I included the `addSkillRelevance` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from this line:

```
per_vacancy_df = per_vacancy_df.append(vacancies.iloc[vacancy_index])
```

The error is occuring because `vacancy_index` is not in the index of the `vacancies` dataframe.